# Delegate alternative for updating progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, delegates, objective-c-blocks

I am currently working on a OSX project using objective C that have somehow a structure based in blocks as follows:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // SYNCHRONOUS task
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // UI update
    });
});
```

It works really nice and having the background task and UI update in the same part of the code makes it much more readable. But I need now to update a progress control, I know that I can do it by using the delegate pattern, but I was wondering if there is a a different and nicer way to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you downloading something using NSURLConnection?

Comment: No, the synchronous task is a little bit more complex, requiring a couple of network connections both as client and server and some processing too...

Comment: I can't suggest something specific for you task, but you can create block variable somewhere in your code and call that block each time when downloading progress updating.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, but are you familiar with KVO?  if not, why not spend some time learning about that in iOS; it's a hugely important issue and would probably help you greatly.

Comment: Yes, I know KVO, but I am trying to find a solution that would make the code more readable, and maybe is a matter of taste, but I consider delegates/notifications/KVO extremely hard to read paradigms, but I think I will have to proceed with delegates. Thank you anyway. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same UI update code, except call it via `dispatch_sync`:

```
// In background thread...
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // Do UI update
});
```